# Отрисовка круга в Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, спрайт

Пишу небольшую игру и столкнулся с проблемой что не могу просто обозначить круг в *pygame*, а его можно только отрисовать

Вот код:

```
class Balls(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = # pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (300, 300), 8)
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.speed = 2

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (300, 300), 8)
```

Я хочу чтобы в *self.image* лежали настройки круга, а в функции *draw* я его уже отрисовывал.

Answer (score 0):

Данные о круге можно записать в переменную как кортеж или список:

```
self.circleData = [RED,(300,300),8]
```

Таким образом вы создадите небольшой массив, который не будет занимать много места в коде, а чтобы потом отобразить этот круг:

```
def draw(self):
     
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,self.circleData[0],self.circleData[1],self.circleData[2])
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!